# Sitecore Rendering Cache not reflecting in Page level caching

Tags: caching, sitecore, rendering

I created Sitecore rendering and added to few pages.  Later, I realized that cache needs to be enabled to improve performance.

But, when I enable cache properties at rendering item level.  It doesn't reflect at item level, when I check in Page Item Presentation details.

Will it show only for new pages?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling cache at the rendering item level enables it to be cached globally. The Cacheable check box that you see when editing the rendering control from the presentation detail screen works a little different. It allows rendering to be cached for that item.

Let us assume that we have a Rendering "Footer" that is added to two items A and B.

If caching is enabled at the rendering item level, HTML would be generated for the "Footer" rendering when either of the items is viewed for the first time. A and B will share the cached HTML and subsequent views of A or B would get the HTML from the cache.

If caching is enabled only at item A through presentation details section, HTML would be cached only for item A. When B is accessed, it will be generated every time.

Also, the value from the "Cacheable" checkbox in the rendering item is a field that is stored along with it. But, the "Cacheable" checkbox you see in the presentation details is stored as part of the rendering field on the presentable item.